# Passing parameters to a Powershell Job using scriptblock

Tags: powershell, start-job

When I use this script works fine

```
$job = start-job -ScriptBlock {param($name);Write-Host $name} -ArgumentList "Test" 
Receive-Job -Job $job
```

But when I do this does not works

```
$scriptblock = {param($name);Write-Host $name}
$job = start-job -ScriptBlock {$scriptblock} -ArgumentList "Test" 
Receive-Job -Job $job
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: 2nd example should simply be `start-job -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -ArgumentList "Test"` (no curly braces)

Comment: Sorry It works fine. Thanks a Lot

Answer (score 2):

Second example is calling a variable `$scriptblock` that is not defined in the job scope if you want to pass in that variable as argument of `-ScriptBlock` parameter then you need to remove the curly braces:

```bash
$scriptblock = { param($name); Write-Host $name }
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -ArgumentList 'Test'
Receive-Job -Job $job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait # Outputs: `Test`
```